# Docker Compose installed but unable to execute from non-sudo user

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed docker-compose on Ubuntu v22.10 x64, and it works properly on root account but not my other account.

I added the user account to docker group, and gave docker group permissions to execute docker-compose file. When I run docker compose version from the user account it says that compose is not a docker command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also run the command `newgrp docker` or log out and log back in? All of the required post-install steps for Linux can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user).